# SQL Server Reporting Services The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

Currently I have the following Issue

I created a Strored procedure that excecutes a dynamic SQL depending on the parameters received on the Report designed in SSRS.

This is the procedure:

```
alter PROCEDURE TablaDinamica @initdate datetime, 
@finaldate datetime, @pin varchar(30), @RID varchar(10), 
@PinState varchar(15), @charger varchar(50), @Document varchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
Declare @Where1 nvarchar(max) = ''
Declare @Where2 nvarchar(max) = ''
Declare @Where3 nvarchar(max) = ''
Declare @Select nvarchar(max)
Declare @FROM nvarchar(max)


if(@initdate IS NOT NULL and @finaldate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @Where1 = 'a.generationdate between ''' + @initdate + ''' and 
'''+ @finaldate + ''''
if(@pin is not null or @pinstate is not null or @NombreRecaudador is not null)
SET @Where1 = @Where1+' and '
END
if(@pin is not null)
BEGIN
SET @Where2= 'pin='''+@pin+''''
if(@pinstate is not null or @charger is not null)
SET @Where2 = @Where2+' and '
END
if(@pinstate IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @Where3 = 'e.Nombre ='''+ @EstadoPin + ''''
if(@charger is not null)
SET @Where3 = @Where3+' and '
END
SET @Select= 'SELECT a.OpRCId,
a.Id,
f.OpClientId,
f.names,
f.lastnames,
f.Birthdate
SET @FROM = 'FROM 
a inner join b ON a.OpId = 
b.OpId
INNER JOIN c ON b.AdId = c.AdId
INNER JOIN d ON c.AdId = d.AdId
INNER JOIN e ON a.CId = e.CId
INNER JOIN f ON b.OpId = f.OpId
INNER JOIN g ON a.AdRId = g.AdRId
INNER JOIN s ON c.AdSId = s.AdSId
WHERE f.document = '''+@Document+''''

EXECUTE(@SELECT+@FROM+@Where1+@where2+@Where3)
END
```

When excecuted, it works perfectly on SSMS, but on SSRS this is the error

```
The multi-part identifier "a.OpRCId" could not be bound.
```

and there is no other indication of anything wrong

I appreciate any help that you can give me!

Regards!

**NOTE:** Per request, this is the schema of a

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[a](
    [OpId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [OpCId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CnEId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OpLId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AdId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CnEId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ANI] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [generationdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [paymentdate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Pin] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Recovery] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [References] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Company] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Total] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [numeric](18, 3) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: To me it seems you are missing some Quotes after f.Birthdate and a space and remove extra comman between f.birthdate and from

Comment: can you post the `schema` of `a`

Comment: Hello, @HolmesIV Thanks, I already made the adjustment in the question

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I already added the schema of a

Comment: @LightningSnake ... looking at the error can you find the same column from your schema?

Comment: @LightningSnake you are calling SELECT a.OpRCId,... clearly from your schema.. that column does NOT exist.. the error literally tells you what the issue is!

Answer (score 0):

> When excecuted, it works perfectly on SSMS, but on SSRS this is the error

Use Profiler to capture the execution from SSRS (including the SET settings from the ExistingSession logon event), and reproduce the issue in SSMS.

Comment: but clearly the `schema` of `a` does not have this column `OpRCId`

Comment: This is what they call an 'XY Problem' here.  Whatever the actual syntax error is, the real problem is OPs inability to repro and diagnose problems when calling procs from SSRS.